# Which word describes the freedom from interference?

Tags: word-request

I usually see people using "privacy" to describe the freedom from intrusion, however this definition does not necessarily includes the interference into a person's matters, only the observation of it. For example, look into someone's private life without consent is a violation of privacy, but changing someone's private life without consent is not. Which word would better describe the latter?

Example sentences:

> I want to move to a my own place to have more ___ since my mom moves the furniture in my room every other month.
>
> There is little ____ in a country where government interferes with your private life all the time.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence with a series of blanks for the word you're looking for.

Comment: "He moved to a house because he had no _____ in his apartment."

Comment: The only thing I can think of at the moment would be the noun **seclusion**. Though, this word doesn't fit your sentences precisely.

Comment: I think that 'seclusion' sounds more like being far from everyone. My question is more like nobody interfering other people's business, even if the are very close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *independence*, *autonomy*, or *self-determination*.

> Many teenagers demand **independence**, but without any of the responsibility that comes with it.

Also *sovereignty*, if you want to pretend you are a self-ruled nation/state.

> North Korea has frequently asserted that UN sanctions intended to curb its development of nuclear weapons are a "violent violation" of its **sovereignty**.
>
> My oh-so clever son, on turning fifteen, declared his room to be a **sovereign** territory and warned that any unauthorized entry could spark a diplomatic incident.

(Edit)  From the dictionary:

> [**Independence**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/independence) (n): 2. *freedom from the control, influence, support, aid, or the like, of others.*

Example:

> In 1776 the American Colonies initiated what would eventually be a "War of **Independence**" to free themselves from British rule.

Comment: These words sound for me something like "doing as wish", rather than "not be done what is not wished".

Comment: @GabrielDiego  In 1776 the American Colonies fought a "War of **Independence**" to free themselves from British rule.   Doesn't that sound like they didn't want to do what someone else told them to do?

Comment: This definitely works with a country, however with people it sounds like end reliance (like financial support) upon someone else (like parents).

Comment: @GabrielDiego  The word "independence" is the same for countries as it is for people.  Even if you choose not to believe me, why don't you just look [it up in a dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/independence) 2. *freedom from the control, influence, support, aid, or the like, of others.*

Comment: I agree with you. I'm choosing your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielDiego  Thanks!  Hope this helps.  All of the suggestions in my answer should work, although "sovereignty" is for *countries* not people, but of course it can be used ironically.

Answer (score 2):

**Sacrosanctity**

(Derived from [**sacrosanct**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sacrosanctity)):

1. : most sacred or holy : INVIOLABLE
2. : treated as if holy : immune from criticism or violation ·
   politically *sacrosanct* programs

**Inviolability / Inviolableness**

(Derived from [**inviolable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inviolable)):

1. : secure from violation or profanation · an *inviolable* law
2. : secure from assault or trespass : unassailable · *inviolable*
   borders

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [discretion](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/discretion) which is defined as:

  > **discretion:** choice, or the right to make a choice, based on judgment.
- Another option is [serenity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serenity) which means:

  > **serenity:** a lack of agitation or disturbance.
- And my last suggestion would be [peace](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/peace) which is defined as:

  > **peace:** calm and quiet; freedom from worry or annoyance.